# Derivation spectrum

Tags: analytical-chemistry

My book doesn't seem to properly explain the importance of derivating the Gaus spectral line, neither the meaning of it, so my questions are :

**1**.What do the spectral lines of 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th derivates of the basic Gaus specter tell us exactly ?

**2**.Why are the second and the fourth derivated spectral lines more used in practice ?

**3**.How does the amplitude of those spectral lines indicate in our results ?

Sorry for the lack of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Derivative spectroscopy* you refer to is a senior technique deployed often in UV-Vis spectroscopy, yet there are examples in the field of infra-red and RAMAN spectroscopy and cyclic dichorism.

1. The theme in common is that at the resolution of the typical
   experiment, while changing the wavelength of observation the
   measured signal alters gradually and continuously and you observe
   for example absorption *bands* -- and not, like in atom absorption
   spectroscopy, for example, discrete absorption *lines*.  The following example sticks to UV-Vis absorption spectroscopy.
2. Often, absorption bands observed consist of several contributions, i.e. there are more than one individual absorptions differing slightly only in terms of their corresponding energy of absorption -- and instead of a pure Gaussian shape of your absorption band, the enveloping absorption band observed features shoulders, for example.
3. To determine the derivative of the spectrum recorded helps to determine the centres of the individual peaks, to ease the discrimination of the individual components of one absorption band.  This may lead to spectral deconvolution. A pictural introduction including examples and limits of application is provided [here](http://www.youngin.com/application/AN-0608-0115EN.pdf).